# how to set 4 columns in desktop view with responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I already added 4 columns in the desktop view using bootstrap but I didn't understand how to set those 4 columns in the responsive view.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has various screen size related class. You can try

4 in desktop, 2 in Ipad/tab and 1 in mobile view.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">info here</div> 
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">info here</div> 
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">info here</div> 
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">info here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col">col</div>
      <div class="col">col</div>
      <div class="col">col</div>
      <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read official documentation from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works). So you can easily learn & use pre-defined **`classes`** of Bootstrap.

**Helpful Links:**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#row-columns
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/#horizontal--vertical-gutters

```css
.l {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<h5 class="mt-4 text-primary">With Columns Break</h5> 
<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 rows-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
    <div class="col l">1</div>
    <div class="col l">2</div>
    <div class="col l">3</div>
    <div class="col l">4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h5 class="mt-4 text-primary">Without Columns Break</h5> 
<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row g-4">
    <div class="col l">1</div>
    <div class="col l">2</div>
    <div class="col l">3</div>
    <div class="col l">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```